# WHERE condition for Intersection table

Tags: sql

Let's assume I have the following intersection table MemberClub:

```
MemberID | ClubId
1        | 2
2        | 1
2        | 2
2        | 3
```

I'd like to get all members which are in the clubs with ID 1 **and** 2. So the result should be member with ID 2.

How would my where statement look like? I tried different variations but I'm not sure which one to choose.

Expected output should be:

```
MemberID | ClubId
2        | 1
2        | 2
```

I need a flexible version which works for a flexible number of clubs (it could be that I want all members being in club with just ID 1. Or all members being in club with ID 2, 4 **and** 6).

Comment: are you asking like "WHERE MemberID = 2 and clubID IN (1,2)"

Comment: Nope. I don't know the MemberID before the execution. I want all members being in club with ID 1 AND 2.

Comment: club with clubID 1 and 2 or MemberID 1 and 2. Can you give the expected result so it would be easy for us to help

Comment: You mean in both clubs, or is one of them enough?

Comment: They should be in both clubs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General `GROUP BY` with `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT)` solution:

```
select MemberID
from MemberClub
WHERE ClubId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY MemberID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ClubId) = 2
```

I.e. make sure there are two different `ClubId`'s for a user.

Alternatively, make sure there are different `ClubId`'s for a user (works just in the two club case):

```
select MemberID
from MemberClub
WHERE ClubId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY MemberID
HAVING max(ClubId) <> min(ClubId)
```

Or skip the `GROUP BY`, do a self `JOIN` instead:

```
select distinct m1.MemberID
from MemberClub m1
    join MemberClub m2 on m1.MemberID = m2.MemberID
where m1.ClubId = 1
  and m2.ClubId = 2
```

---

To return members who are in all clubs:

```
select MemberID
from MemberClub
GROUP BY MemberID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ClubId) = (select count(distinct ClubId) from MemberClub)
```

Comment: Is there a more flexible way? The first version works for two clubs only. What when they should be in club 1, 3 and 4? The second doesn't work for one club I guess.

Comment: Use first query in that case, much more flexible and easy to adjust.

Comment: First one works only with 2 clubs. Not flexible enough. I would always have to find out the number of the clubs.

Comment: You mean you want the query to find out the number of different clubs, and return the users who are members of all of them?

Comment: The first version where you GROUP BY and then COUNT works for me, although it's not ideally.